# AMD tag: Advanced Micro Devices or Asynchronous Module Definition?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

- [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices)
- [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

The [AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd) tag is ambiguous and there seems to be a roughly even split in its application - between processor-specific questions and JavaScript library questions.

Only 127 tagged questions at time of writing, but this may grow as many popular JavaScript libraries are adopting [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) for interoperability.

Should we nip this one in the bud or is this just small fry? How should these questions be re-tagged?

Comment: I suppose AMD (the company) should retain the AMD tag since they own the trademark and the JavaScript AMD should be re-tagged as either JavaScript-AMD or AMD-JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691 - I hadn't noticed it when I posted this, but the [js-amd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js-amd) tag has some traction.